# After facebook login, how go to another activity from viewpager ?

Tags: android, facebook

I have a facebook login button on a viewpager with circlepageindicator. 
When i click on that, it authenticates the user and changes login button to logout there itself.

What i want is that, **(1).** user should be directed to a new activity ( which is my navigation drawer activity) with the session. **(2).** how do i pass/authenticate sessions between each activity and for each api requests ?

Here is my MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
ViewPager pager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

     MyPagerAdapter adapter=new MyPagerAdapter();
     pager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
     pager.setAdapter(adapter);     
     pager.setCurrentItem(0);

     //Bind the title indicator to the adapter
     CirclePageIndicator titleIndicator = (CirclePageIndicator)findViewById(R.id.titles);
     titleIndicator.setViewPager(pager);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            // Add the fragment on initial activity setup
            mainFragment = new MainFragment();
            getSupportFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction()
            .add(android.R.id.content, mainFragment)
            .commit();
        } else {
            // Or set the fragment from restored state info
            mainFragment = (MainFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(android.R.id.content);
        }
      }
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (pager.getCurrentItem() == 0) {
        // If the user is currently looking at the first step, allow the system to handle the
        // Back button. This calls finish() on this activity and pops the back stack.
        super.onBackPressed();
    } else {
        // Otherwise, select the previous step.
        pager.setCurrentItem(pager.getCurrentItem() - 1);
    }
}




}
```

Here is my MainFragment.java

```
public class MainFragment extends Fragment {

private static final String TAG = "MainFragment";

private UiLifecycleHelper uiHelper;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, 
        ViewGroup container, 
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, container, false);

    LoginButton authButton = (LoginButton) view.findViewById(R.id.authButton);
    authButton.setFragment(this);

    return view;
}

private Session.StatusCallback callback = new Session.StatusCallback() {
    @Override
    public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
        onSessionStateChange(session, state, exception);
    }
};

private void onSessionStateChange(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
    if (state.isOpened()) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Logged in...");

        // Request user data and show the results
        Request.newMeRequest(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
                if (user != null) {

                    Log.i(TAG, user.getName()+" ***** "+user.getBirthday());

                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Logged In", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
            }
        }).executeAsync();


    } else if (state.isClosed()) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Logged out...");

    }
}



@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    uiHelper = new UiLifecycleHelper(getActivity(), callback);
    uiHelper.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
    if (session != null &&
           (session.isOpened() || session.isClosed()) ) {
        onSessionStateChange(session, session.getState(), null);
    }

    uiHelper.onResume();
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    uiHelper.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);


}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    uiHelper.onPause();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    uiHelper.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    uiHelper.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}

}
```

Referred many examples but couldn't succeed. Stuck with this from many days.

Any suggestions accepted. Thank you.

[image][image]

Answer (score 3):

When Call Back comes from facebook

```
 Request.newMeRequest(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
                if (user != null) {
                      ....
```

When `user != null`  you should get user data and then start the new activity

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), HomeActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("Fb_id", user.getId());
intent.putExtra("user_name", user.getName());
startActivity(intent);
```

Every time you want to get the facebook open session

```
Session currentSession = Session.getActiveSession();
```

Answer (score 0):

In the onSessionStateChange method, do what you want after a successful login, in the below sample I am redirecting the page to main dashboard.

```
private void onSessionStateChange(Session session, SessionState state,Exception exception) {
    if (state.isOpened()) {
        //Succussful Loggin
        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), Dashboard.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    } else if (state.isClosed()) {
        //Loggedout
    }
}
```